# android development java searchManager OnCancelListener fails to start activity onCancel method

Tags: java, android, android-searchmanager

I am trying to trigger an onCancel() when the user exit of the search dialog by pressing the left arrow button, but this never occurs. I tried register the cancel listener in the main activity OnCreate(), or in onViewCreated() ; also in the fragment using the search box. The code :

```
final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchManager.setOnCancelListener(
    new SearchManager.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("cancel","--------------");
        }
    }
);
```

The Log.e line is never called.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the [SearchView guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#LifeCycle) says:

> If the user cancels search by pressing the Back button, the search dialog closes and the activity regains input focus. You can register to be notified when the search dialog is closed with setOnDismissListener() and/or setOnCancelListener(). You should need to register only the OnDismissListener, because it is called every time the search dialog closes. The OnCancelListener only pertains to events in which the user explicitly exited the search dialog, so it is not called when a search is executed (in which case, the search dialog naturally disappears).

So if you want to handle **dismissal that occurs after user has searched (search is executed)** then you must handle it by implementing [OnDismissListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnDismissListener).

If you want to handle **cancellation that occurs when the searchview is closed without doing any search (search is not executed)** then you handle it in an [OnCancelListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnCancelListener).

You can handle the both as well.

Comment: It is what does not work (see my post)

Comment: `onCancel` is not being called despite the back button pressed without executing search?

Comment: yep, it is not :-(
I tried to put it into the activity, into the fragment owning the search, at other places, but no success

Comment: @JeanBain can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It would be appropriate. I have changed my application logic, so I don't need it anymore ; but I'm going to try from an Android studio generated source